# issues after upgrading to ubuntu 14.04 from 13.10

Tags: 14.04

After getting the no more support message I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 it seemed to go fine but after about a minute the computer rebooted then there after it would reboot every 30 sec.-2 minutes.

It does not even give time to backup my data so that I can reinstall to 13.10

Comment: Have you tried booting from Live Media? This might allow you to copy your data to an external drive while you're waiting for a solution to the rebooting problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to back up your data, I'm not saying "don't do that" but you can reinstall 14.04 without loosing all the stuff like downloads and whatnot in your home folder.

You can choose to update your existing version (even though it's the same version) and it will install over all the program folders but will leave your home folder and all your downloads, music, etc intact.

You will have to reinstall the stuff you downloaded from apt-get or installed from the software center. All of that stuff gets replaced with the default setup.